# VPN connection using App Extension

Tags: ios, vpn, nevpnmanager, networkextension

I am using `NEVPNManager` to configure and connect VPN connection. Working great in App. Now i am integrating Today's App Extension to connect VPN. Problem im facing that Extension and App are creating different profile. How to use single VPN profile in both App and App Extension?

Comment: post your code from todays extension

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with same situation. Use the shared keychain space, it will help you to transfer data back and forth.

Thanks.